# HttpPost function in controller doesn't get called

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

for some reason 3 of my HttpPost functions in my controller doesn't get called. I tried remaking the views under different names but had no success. They all return to the Index view instead of running the HttpPost function.

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult OrderIsFinished(string PickUp, string DeliveryBigger, string DeliverySmaller)
    {
        string view = "";

        if (PickUp != null)
        {
            view = "OrderPickUp";
        }

        if (DeliveryBigger != null)
        {
            view = "DeliveryBigger";
        }

        if (DeliverySmaller != null)
        {
            view = "DeliverySmaller";
        }

        return View(view);
    }
```

View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "OrderIsFinished";
}

@section shoppingcart {
    <p>Shopping Cart</p>
 }

<h2>OrderIsFinished</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <input type="submit" name="PickUp" value="Ik kom mijn bestelling afhalen" />
    <input type="submit" name="DeliveryBigger" value="Ik wil dat u mijn bestelling levert" />
    <input type="submit" name="DeliverySmaller" value="Ik wil dat u mijn bestelling  levert" />
}
```

When I put a breakpoint at the function, I don't there and it just returns the Index view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try implicit point action and controller name

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("OrderIsFinished","ControllerName",FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="submit" name="PickUp" value="Ik kom mijn bestelling afhalen" />
    <input type="submit" name="DeliveryBigger" value="Ik wil dat u mijn bestelling levert" />
   <input type="submit" name="DeliverySmaller" value="Ik wil dat u mijn bestelling  levert" />
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This solution works! Any reason why some views work without this and some need this?

Comment: @NanouPonette it probably has to do with the parameters that you have in your post method. If you have parameter less post method it could probably work without implicitly pointing method, controller and form method type.

Comment: Hmmmm ok. Thx for helping. I will watch out for this in the future.